# React native load css and js Webview

Tags: webview, react-native

I want to load custom html in a webview using react native, it's working for simple html but I can't figure out how to load javascript from a js file to the webview, it looks like nothing happen.

Here is my webview :

```
 var html = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><script src="myfile.js" type="text/javascript"></script></head><body><h1>This is a heading!</h1><div id="here"></div></body></html>';

    return (
      <WebView html={html}
               javaScriptEnabled={true} />
    );
```

And here I have my simple js file (myfile.js):

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
   alert("HERE");
   var generateHere = document.getElementById("here");
generateHere.innerHTML = '<div class="someclass"><a href="www.example.com"><p>some text</p></a></div>';
});
```

I tried it in my web browsers it works.

Comment: Edit : I already find this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33818641/inject-javascript-or-css-into-react-native-webview-before-page-renders

Comment: Where did you place your `myfile.js`?

Comment: in the Xcode project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `injectedJavaScript` attribute on the WebView to pass over JS to be executed.

For example:

```
<WebView html={html}
    injectedJavaScript={'function myfunc() { //your JS here };myfunc();'}
    javaScriptEnabled={true} />
```

Comment: How is it possible to load css into the webview with this method?

Comment: Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe you could inject css via JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

[scgough's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34659917/10871073) injects JS; here is how you can also inject CSS with JavaScript:

```
<WebView html={html}
    injectedJavaScript={`let customCSS = "body { font-weight: 'bold'; font-size: '17px'; }"//your CSS
    let headTag = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    let styleTag = document.createElement('style')
    headTag.appendChild(styleTag);
    styleTag.type = 'text/css';
    styleTag.appendChild(document.createTextNode(customCSS));`}
    javaScriptEnabled={true} />
```