# Is there any way to add custom CSS For HTML rendered inside a WebView in React Native?

Tags: javascript, ios, css, webview, react-native

I want to add custom css for my html rendered inside a webview of react native. Is there any possibility or workaround to add it. I have tried through injectedJavascript propperty but its not working. Or are there any other solutions for this.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React native load css and js Webview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34644382/react-native-load-css-and-js-webview)