# how to load the css file from react native-webview in ios device?

Tags: react-native, webview, react-native-ios

I was loading a static html file when I use web view.

The html file is loaded well, but the (css & js) file is not loaded from iOS.(not reading js & css)

(* android is working very well)

I want to load css and js file with html file in ios.

Can you help me?

- below my react native code

```
const ChartHTML =
    Platform.OS === 'ios'
      ? require('./iosChart/chart.html')
      : {
          uri: 'file:///android_asset/chart.html',
          baseUrl: 'file:///android_asset/Resources',
        };

<WebView
        originWhitelist={['*']}
        scrollEnabled={false}
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
        domStorageEnabled={true}
        allowFileAccess={true}
        ref={ref}
        source={ChartHTML}
        nativeConfig={{props: {webContentsDebuggingEnabled: true}}}
        allowFileAccessFromFileURLs={true}
        allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs={true}
        onError={e => console.log(e)}
```

- below my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
    <script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/css" src="./chart.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chartdiv" class="test">fe</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

- directory

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3ujR.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34644382/react-native-load-css-and-js-webview

Comment: sorry, it's not good solution in my project